# PyKalman's EM algorithm and the AR(I)MA state-space equations

Tags: python, kalman-filter, arima, state-space, pykalman

I am using Python's **PyKalman** to run the Kalman filter based on the **ARMA**(p,q) model. The transition matrix should take a very particular form (see, for instance, page 374 of [Hamilton's "Times Series Analysis"](https://hhstokes.people.uic.edu/ftp/e538/state_space.pdf) for the AR(p) example) with some **ones** and **zeros** in the right places. When I use PyKalman's **EM algorithm**, however, it produces a **transition matrix** of a completely general form. Since the ones and the zeros are gone, the **state-space model** doesn't correspond anymore to the ARMA setting.

How  can I use the EM method of the PyKalman package, while keeping the transition matrix in the very particular ARMA form?

Comment: Is the matrix initially unknown? I would say it should be known and is not a subject of em optimization, is it?

Comment: In the simplest version of the Kalman filter these parameters/matrices are indeed set to fixed known values. For the practical purposes, however, it is not always sufficient, as there is no straightforward way to guess them. It is therefore common to use the expectation–maximization (EM) algorithm to determine the maximum likelihood estimates of the parameters. At least, this is the impression I got :)

Comment: I see. So you want the EM algorithm to estimate the transition matrix and you need to know how to restrict the estimator to generate it in the ARMA way.

Comment: You got it absolutely right